# Error when trying to filter on a property of an entity inheriting from another in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type

When I have entity B inherit from entity A using table-per-type for storage and try to write a Linq query that filters on a property on B, for example

```
Function(b) b.name="Joe"
```

I get the error

> The specified type member 'name' is
>   not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are
>   supported.

Filtering on any of the properties that exist in the base table works fine. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bags/archive/2009/03/06/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance.aspx). I needed to add **.OfType(MySubClass)()** to my entity in the from clause to see the subclass properties.